# Does has_many require belongs_to on the other side?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

If `Parent has_many :children`, **must** `Child :belongs_to :parent`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, the `belongs_to` isn't necessary. It will mean that you won't be able to query the association from both directions, but if that's not a requirement for your app, then it's not necessary.

Comment: Do you know if this is still accurate in the latest Rails? I've done a bit of looking and I think it is, but I'm not certain, and it'd be great for the first Google result to be accurate.

Answer (score 12):

As Cody says, not mandatory - but will be the 90% case.

See the [Rails API Doc for ActiveRecord Associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).
When you specify either `has_many` or `belongs_to`, a bunch of (helper) methods get added to your Rails Model class. The page above shows the specific methods that get added automatically in tabular format. So if you just specify one end of the association e.g. the Child, you'd only be able to use those corresponding methods from the Child model.